# How to add Coupon code option on Stripe window in Angular 8+?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, stripe-payments

I am trying to add input option on stripe payment gateway when handler is open in front End.
I have a stripe window opened and want to show an input for coupons.

```js
// Load Stripe Function on ngOnInit : 
   loadStripe() {
     if(!window.document.getElementById('stripe-script')) {
       var s = window.document.createElement("script");
       s.id = "stripe-script";
       s.type = "text/javascript";
       s.src = "https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js";
       window.document.body.appendChild(s);
     }
   }

    var handler =  (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
    key : <STRIPE KEY>

      locale: 'auto',
      token: async  (token: any)=> {
        const url = '';
        const data = {id : token.id , amount : amount*100 };
        await fetch(url ,{ ... })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then( async (data) => {}
        });
      }
    });
     handler.open({});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the legacy Checkout, and there's no way to modify it in any way.  You may want to switch to the new Checkout, which does support coupons: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/discounts

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I tried with the latest version but it requires SSL certificate. Also can you share any implementation with the latest version.

Comment: The legacy version also requires an SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using client-only integration? If so, there are some limitations and promotional code/coupon is one of them as specified: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client

> Coupons, Discounts, Promotion codes, and Tax rates are not supported.

If you have server-sided implementaton, then you can set the `allow_promotion_codes` parameter: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-allow_promotion_codes

If you do not have any server-implementation but still want to support the coupon feature, then you can consider a serverless approach such as AWS Lambda.

It also seems like you're using an outdated version of Checkout. Do refer to the latest Checkout integration guide that uses `PaymentIntent`, `PaymentMethod` and `SetupIntent` rather than `Tokens` and `Sources`.